# Adobe Illustrator CS6 64-bit no longer works on Catalina!

Tags: applications, catalina, adobe, 32-bit

I read somewhere that Adobe Illustrator CS6 is 64-bit and able to run on Catalina.  I did run a 64-bit software check on OSX Mojave to double-confirm that it is 64-bit before upgrading to Catalina.

I am now left with a defunct Illustrator and Photoshop which I needed to rush my stuff!

This is what I see on my dock after Catalina upgrade!

> [image]

Comment: [Photoshop CS6 is a 64-bit executable…but a bunch of associated helper apps are 32-bit.

Has anyone actually tried to run Photoshop CS6 on Catalina? Does it even launch successfully? If so, is it usable?](https://twitter.com/siracusa/status/1182281280316203010)